# Higher Order Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I am trying to obtain the general solution of the following Diophantine equation.
$$x^4-8x^2y^2+8y^4=z^2$$
My approach was to rewrite the equation.
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
& x^4+z^2=2(2y^2-x^2)^2\\
\implies & p^2+q^2=2r^2
\end{split}
\end{align}
Let $a^2+b^2=r^2$. After some manipulation,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
& (a^2+b^2)+(a^2+b^2)=2r^2 \\
& (a^2+b^2+2ab)+(a^2+b^2-2ab)=2r^2 \\
& (a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=2r^2
\end{split}
\end{align}
$(a,b,c)$ forms a Pythagorean triple. So we get
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&(a,b,c)=(k(m^2-n^2),2kmn,k(m^2+n^2))\\
&(p,q,r)=(x^2,y^2,z)=(k(m^2-n^2+2mn),k(m^2+mn),k(m^2+n^2))
\end{split}
\end{align}
I am stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that not all pythagorean triples can be described that way. It applies only to primitive pythagorean triples, so you might want to include a multiple $k$.

Comment: Try $x\in\mathbb{Z}\quad y=0\lor y=\pm x\quad z=\pm x^2$

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, I should have included the multiplication factor. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Althogh this method is different from your method, the solution is easy to derive.

Let $U=\frac{\large{x}}{\large{y}}, V=\frac{\large{z}}{\large{y^2}}$ then we get $V^2 = U^4-8U^2+8$.
This quartic equation is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve below.
$Y^2 = X^3 + X^2 -3X + 1$
$U = \frac{Y}{(X-1)}, V = \frac{X^3-3X^2+X+1}{(X-1)^2}$
$X = \frac{1}{2}V+\frac{1}{2}U^2-1, Y = \frac{1}{2}U(V+U^2-4)$

This elliptic curve has rank $1$ with generator $(0,-1)$.
The rank and generator are obtainded using mwrank(Cremona).
Hence this curve has infinitely many rational points.
Thus, we get infinitely many integer solutions.

Example:
First, we get a rational solution $(X,Y)=(\frac{-56}{25}, \frac{153}{125})$ using mwrank or Magma.
From $U = \frac{Y}{(X-1)}, V = \frac{X^3-3X^2+X+1}{(X-1)^2}$, we get $(U,V)=(\frac{-17}{45}, \frac{-5311}{2025})$
Hence we get $(x,y,z)=(17,45,5311).$

More solutions using group law:

Let $P(X,Y)=(0,-1)$, then we get
$6P(X,Y)=(\frac{30547621}{2340900}, \frac{-173783774969}{3581577000})$
$7P(X,Y)=(\frac{-6037269840}{7661325841}, \frac{-1253783210541679}{670588189536889}).$
Hence we get the corresponding solutions
$(x,y,z)=(32721479, 8125830, 784659483951841)$
$(x,y,z)=(10712341919, 10244481689, 70259696347563139199).$

Some solutions with $x<1000000$ using PARI-GP as follows.
"hyperellratpoints($X^4-8X^2+8,1000000$)"

```
           [ x  y  z ]
            
           [1, 1, 1]
           [7, 2, 31]
           [17, 45, 5311]
           [2273, 868, 305791]
           [50639, 98069, 23436127681]
```

Comment: All very nice but as a solution it has a drawback: You have to prove bi-rationality, that the range is $1$ and that $(0, -1)$ is a generator. All this is somewhat sophisticated and if the answer is copied as such from some source it must be cited.

Comment: @Tomita Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain a bit about how to get  a solution for original problem given a solution of the elliptic curve?

Comment: @guest123456 I edited it.

Comment: Thanks @Tomita for your time. I am not familiar to such high level topics. Is there any generic way to find rational points on an elliptic curve, or we have to use softwares for that?

Comment: @guest123456 I usually use mwrank, Online Magma calculator, and Sage(mwrank is included).

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. Using Sagemath, I got a slightly different curve $y^2=x^3+x^2-17x+15$, for this problem. How did you calculate those rational solutions?

Comment: @guest123456 How did you transform quartic curve to elliptic curve?
I guess there is not such a tool in sagemath.

Comment: @guest123456 If we just find the rational points of quartic curve, we can use PARI-GP( see hyperellratpoints command).

Comment: @Tomita I used the method described at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/36637/change-of-variable-from-hyperellictic-curve-to-weierstrass-form/

Comment: @guest123456 Since Y^2 = X^3 + X^2 -3X + 1(A256) is different from y^2=x^3+x^2-17x+15(A192) by Cremona's database, I guess there is something wrong with the code or how to use it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Something seems wrong in that code. Using Jacobian in Sagemath I got the same curve.

Comment: Two curves of distinct equations  $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ and genus $1$ (i.e. elliptic) could be birrationally equivalent.

Comment: @Piquito  

Two elliptic curves are birationally equivalent if and only if their j-invariants are the same.  
j-invariant of $Y^2 = X^3 + X^2 -3X + 1$ is $ 8000 $, another is $ \frac{35152}{9} $.
Hence two curves are not birrationally equivalent.

Comment: @piepie Could you clarify, how you got the same curve?  I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the birationally equivalent curve...

Comment: @Alex You can use the function Jacobian in Sagemath. See https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8766/elliptic-curves-in-quartic-and-standard-form/